# Where can we see the custom event of Application Insight in Power BI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights

When importing data from Application Insight to Power BI, all the options that are there are related to page views and sessions. But I am not able to plot in the report the custom events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported. We are working to enable this functionality soon

Comment: what about Trace, Dependency, Exception, Request. Are these also under development. ?